# Xamarin.Forms Hockey App Error CrashManager.Register

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, hockeyapp

Currently, I follow the documentation of [Hockey App for Android](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-cross-platform/how-to-integrate-hockeyapp-with-xamarin) but when I build the Solution, the Error shows as below Error."**CrashManager does not contain a definition of Register**"
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using statement says: `using HockeyApp;` it should be `using HockeyApp.Android;`.